# How to insert Duplicated data only into an Event Log?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I need help regarding a SQL query problem. I have a query where I am able to delete the duplicates but I also need to create records of the duplicated data being deleted into a EventLog in which I am clueless about it. Below is an example of my Student Table. From the table below, you can see only Alpha and Bravo are duplicated

```
id   Name   Age  Group  
-----------------------
1    Alpha  11    A 
2    Bravo  12    A

3    Alpha  11    B      
4    Bravo  12    B
5    Delta  11    B
```

As I am copying data from Group A to Group B, I need to find & delete the duplicated data in group B. Below is my query on deleting duplicates from Group B.

```
DELETE Student WHERE id 
IN (SELECT tb.id 
FROM Student AS ta 
JOIN Student AS tb ON ta.name=tb.name AND ta.age=tb.age 
WHERE ta.GroupName='A' AND tb.GroupName='B')
```

Here is an example of my eventlog and how I want the query that I execute to like.

```
id   Name   Age  Group Status
------------------------------------------
1    Alpha  11    B    Delete
2    Bravo  11    B    Delete
```

Instead of inserting the entire Group B data into the eventlog, is there any query that can just insert the **Duplicated Data** into the event log?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (That code is product specific.)

Answer (score 0):

Run this before the Delete above. Not sure how you decide what one is the duplicate but you can use Row_Number to list them with the non duplicate at as 1 and and then insert everything with a row_Number > 1

```
; WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT Name
          ,Age
          ,[Group]
          ,STATUS = 'Delete'
          ,RID = ROW_NUMBER ( )  OVER ( PARTITION BY Name,Age  ORDER BY Name)  
    FROM Student AS ta 
    JOIN Student AS tb ON ta.name=tb.name AND ta.age=tb.age         
)

    INSERT INTO EventLog
    SELECT Name,Age,[Group],'Delete'
    FROM cte
    WHERE RID > 1
```

Comment: I use Name & Age to decide on the duplicates. if both Name & age are exactly the same, it is considered a Duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

If we are speaking about Microsoft sql, key is output clause, more details here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

```
declare @Student table
( id int, name nvarchar(20), age int,"groupname" char(1)) 

insert into @student values (1,  'Alpha' , 11,    'A' ),
(2,    'Bravo' , 12,    'A'),
(3    ,'Alpha' , 11 ,   'B'),      
(4    ,'Bravo'  ,12 ,   'B'),
(5    ,'Delta'  ,11 ,   'B')

declare @Event table
( id int, name nvarchar(20), age int,"groupname" char(1),"Status" nvarchar(20)) 


select * from @Student   

DELETE @Student 
output deleted.*, 'Deleted' into @Event
WHERE id 
IN (SELECT tb.id 
FROM @Student AS ta 
JOIN @Student AS tb ON ta.name=tb.name AND ta.age=tb.age 
WHERE ta.GroupName='A' AND tb.GroupName='B')

select * from @event
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create basic trigger after delete in student table, this query will be executed after any deletion process in student table  and will insert deleted record into log_table

```
create trigger deleted_records 
  on student_table
  after delete
as
begin 
 insert into log_table  
 select d.id, d.Name, d.Age, d.Group, 'DELETED'
 from DELETED d;

end
```